# Logic circuit for not accidentally driving a GPIO output

Tags: gpio, encryption

I am developing a system which will have several devices attached to it. I will have a massive software running on it which controls all of the devices and communicates with different units.

One of the devices sprays all of its paint content at once when triggered. It is a third party device, it is tightly sealed, I cannot remove the paint container from it. It needs to be connected to the system all the time, because I need to communicate with it periodically. And when it is triggered, it becomes useless, and needs to be replaced with a new one.

The problem is, if I accidentally trigger this output during the development stage, it will create a real mass in the laboratory, and it will cost money since it needs to be replaced. I want to avoid this as much as possible.

As a solution, I came up with an idea of inserting a logic circuit between the MCU and the device. If a certain sequence of logic pattern (e.g.; 010, 110 and 011) is sent from the GPIO outputs, it will trigger the device. I want to avoid an accident because of shorting this GPIO wire to logic-high state, or changing it in the code.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy2pOQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What other means can be used? Is there an IC (which is controlled over GPIO, I<sup>2</sup>C or SPI) for this purpose?

Comment: Surely something like this could be built, but it kind of moves the problem to elsewhere. The built circuit must be made absolutely sure not to trigger by accident, for example at powerup or powerdown, or if it is an I2C or SPI IO expander, chances are that those can have glitches on their output too, or during your developement, you can have a bug that accidentally configures the ports so that it triggers. Or the code might accidentally jump to execute the trigger function, no matter what hardware interlocks are in place. Perhaps another small MCU with serial port comms could handle this?

Comment: Can't you just use an empty one (or some kind of dummy) during development?

Comment: I understand that you need the thing connected during development for comms and such, but couldn't you just not connect that one pin? Seems like a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do the trick if the firing of your device is not absolutely time critical. It requires a string of 0101010..... to allow the small cap to pump enough charge into the large cap to fire the schmmit triggered buffer. The cap and discharge resistor on the input to the schmitt will make it stable at power up.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHvc2q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are absolutely correct in avoiding DC signalling in this type of situation. In addition the software should be structured so that this output is only ever controlled from one place (subroutine) and that this subroutine carries out all the safety checks before this is fired. (do you want to fire? are you sure you really want to fire?......)